# Bash - Pointer to Value in Associate Array?

Tags: arrays, bash, pointers, associative-array

Is there a way in `Bash` to make a *pointer* to the *value* of a key in an **associate array**? Like this:

```
declare -A mapp
mapp=( ["key"]="${value}" )

for k in "${!mapp[@]}"; do 
    pointer="${mapp["${k}"]}"   # How do I do this?
done
```

Usually, you do not *need* to use a pointer, but I'm curious to see if there's a way to make one.

In a simpler situation (i.e., for normal/string variables), I would make a pointer like this:

```
pointer=b
read -p "Enter something: " b
eval pointer=\$${pointer}
```

How would I do this for an associate array? This doesn't work (skip the strikethroughed code):

```
declare -A mapp
mapp=( ["first"]="${a}"  ["second"]="${b}" )

for k in "${!mapp[@]}"; do 
    v=mapp["${k}"]

    read -p "Enter ${k}: " new

    eval v=\$${v}    # Doesn't work

done
```

```
declare -A mapp
mapp=( ["first"]="${a}"  ["second"]="${b}" )

for k in "${!mapp[@]}"; do 
    v=mapp["${k}"]

    read -p "Enter ${k}: " k

    eval v=\$${v}    # Doesn't work

done
```

This doesn't work either (skip the strikethroughed code):

```
declare -A mapp
mapp=( ["first"]="${a}"  ["second"]="${b}" )

for k in "${!mapp[@]}"; do 
    v=mapp

    read -p "Enter ${k}: " new

    eval v=\$${v["${k}"]}    # Doesn't work (and has terrible readability)

done
```

```
declare -A mapp
mapp=( ["first"]="${a}"  ["second"]="${b}" )

for k in "${!mapp[@]}"; do 
    v=mapp

    read -p "Enter ${k}: " k

    eval v=\$${v["${k}"]}    # Doesn't work (and has terrible readability)

done
```

Comment: So you don't mean "pointer" here at all really? You mean how do you indirectly/etc. get the value from array?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I messed up something in my code. I'm trying to use the pointer to change the value in the array.

Comment: What about `pointer="${mapp["${k}"]}"` didn't work to get `pointer` to have the value you wanted? (Other than the inner quotes being unnecessary and wrong.) Or do you really mean a "pointer" (of sorts) so you can then use `$pointer` to get the *current* value from the associative array?

Comment: None of your examples are about assigning through the "pointer". Perhaps you want to fix that?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `bash` 4.3, you can use a nameref:

```
$ mapp=([key]=value)
$ declare -n x=mapp[key]  # NO dollar sign!
$ x=7
$ echo ${mapp[key]}
7
```

Before 4.3, you need to use the `declare` command differently to do the indirection.

```
$ mapp=([key]=value)
$ x=mapp[key]  # NO dollar sign!
$ declare "$x=7"
$ echo ${mapp[key]}
7
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I never thought to check the options for `declare`.

Answer (score 1):

No problem:

```
$ declare -A ary=([foo]=bar [baz]=qux)
$ key=foo
$ pointer="ary[$key]"
$ echo "$pointer"
ary[foo]
$ echo "${!pointer}"
bar
```

A "pointer" in this sense is an [indirect variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: Ah, I missed the point about using the "pointer" to *set* a value.

Comment: That's ok. So did the OP for a while. =)

Comment: Touché `Etan Reisner` :P